# MySQL selecting 0 matches all strings

Tags: mysql

If I have a table with a string column, and try to select from that column matching `0`, all rows are returned. Why would MySQL return all rows, instead of just the rows that have 0 as the string?

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyStringColumn = 0;
```

Take a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/10533/0). I would expect to see no rows returned, but all are. Why does this happen?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/10534

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison command

```
WHERE info = 0
```

casts `info` as an integer.  Unless it starts with some string of digits, its integer value is zero.  So all your strings except stuff like '123abc' will match.

Comment: If I explicit cast his `details` column to an integer it returns an error (cannot convert "something" to integer). What explains that it can cast it in the WHERE clause but not explicitly using `convert(int, details)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use
    WHERE MyStringColumn = '0'